# Sinon stub an object containing sync and async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, decorator, sinon, stub

I am working on a project where I am observing types of each binding layer function that node.js javascript layer calls. For observing types, I created a stub using `sinon` that looks something like this

```
var originalProcessBinding = process.binding;
sinon.stub(process, 'binding').callsFake(function (data) {
  var res = originalProcessBinding(data);
  // custom code here
  return res;
}
```

So, my idea is to look at each `object` inside `res` and see if its a `Function`. If it is, create a stub that records the state and then call the original `Function`. The `custom code` looks something like

```
_.forEach(res, function(value, key) {
  if (_.isFunction(value)) {
    sinon.stub(res, key).callsFake(function() {
      var args = arguments;
      // do some processing with the arguments
      save(args);
      // call the original function
      return value(...arguments);
    }
  }
}
```

However, I am not sure if this handles all the types of returns. For instance, how are the errors handled? What happens if the function is asynchronous?

I ran the `node.js` test suite and found lots of failing test cases. Is there a better way to stub the functions. Thanks.

Edit: The failing test cases have errors in common that look like `Callback was already called`  or `Timeout` or `Expected Error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, even though many errors can be fixed, It's hard to add `sinon` to the build process. I implemented by own stubbing methods in vanilla js to fix this. Anyone who's looking to stub internal `node.js` functions should find this helpful.

```
(function() { process.binding = function(args) {
    const org = process.binding;
    const util = require('util');

    var that = org(args),
      thatc = that;
      for (let i in thatc) {
        if (util.isFunction(thatc[i]) && (!thatc[i].__isStubbed)) {
          let fn = thatc[i];
          if (i[0] !== i[0].toUpperCase()) {
            // hacky workaround to avoid stubbing function constructors.
            thatc[i] = function() {
              save(arguments);
              return fn.apply(that, arguments);
            }
            thatc[i].__isStubbed = true; 
          }
        }
      }
    return thatc;
  } 
})();
```

This code passes all the tests with the current master of Node.js. Adding `sinon` seems to mutate the function object that triggers internal v8 checks which fail.